# What does " LOOP $ " means ?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

In an assembly example I find this :
[image]

There is no label named " $ " . What does this " LOOP $ " ?
where is the starting of this loop ?
please explain . Thanks in advance .

Comment: If my rusty memory serves me right, the `$` is the address of the current instruction. IOW, `mov cx,<const>` + `loop $` is just a delay: loop in one place for `<const>` iterations.

Comment: Note that this is not good way to implement a delay on a PC these days.  On modern PC that delay loop probably runs orders of magnitude faster than the original programmer intended.

Comment: It even says "delay" in the line above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` is the address the current instruction starts at: `LOOP $` is thus an empty loop of CX repetitions.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure but probably this is equivalent to:

```
L3:    LOOP L3
```

In other words, small delay from loop 0xB000..0